# котов and Петров

Tags: этимология, значения, литература

This is a follow up to [this question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/819/do-these-surnames-imply-anything).

Here is a Daniil Kharms short story:

> *ПЕТРОВ И КАМАРОВ*
>
> **ПЕТРОВ:**
>     Эй, Камаров!
>     Давай ловить комаров!
>   **КАМАРОВ:**
>     Нет, я к этому еще не готов.
>     Давай лучше ловить котов!

Here since Petrov is teasing Kamarov, I expect, the `котов` (cats, tomcats?) Kamarov's answer to be somehow related to `Петров`. But I'm not able to find any relation in between (I cannot read Russian at all, I'm simply using some translation tools and dictionaries to dig the meanings).

Can anyone explain if there is an implied relation between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `котов` is related to `готов`, not to `Петров`. The sounds produced by `г` and `к` are close to each other (that's a pair of voiced and unvoiced consonants), so the words sound similar.

Comment: I see that similarity, but since Petrov is suggesting catching the `gnats` (related to `Kamarov`), I expect what Kamarov suggests (cat) should be related to Petrov. So what you say is that there is no such relation between `cat` and `Petrov`?

Comment: @canpolat Correct, there is absolutely no relationship to cats there: the last name `Петров` is based on the first name `Пётр` (Peter) which comes from Greek `Πετρος` (stone).

Comment: Thank you! I marked response as the answer. But I have a question: if there is no such relation, I don't really understand the humor here. Petrov says: "Let's catch some mosquitos" and Mosquitov replies: "I'm not ready, let's catch some cats instead". Is that all?

Comment: @canpolat I think the humor here is that `Камаров` does not catch the relation between `комаров` and his last name, taking the suggestion to catch mosquitoes literally.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for my very bad english but i try to expalin you humor of this. I'ts easy. Here We have simple game of words - 1) КАМАРОВ(last name Kamarov, based on word КОМАР - Mosquit) - кОмаров (mosquitos) 
and 2) готов (i'm ready) - котов(cats). Just game of words, no hidden meaning.

Comment: this game of words is called rhyme )))

Comment: You're correct, it's a game of words.

Answer (score 1):

Vasily Petrov-Komarov - the first authentic Soviet serial maniac, handled in Moscow in the period 1921-1923. His victims included 33 men.

All  his crimes committed on one scenario: meet with a client who wanted to buy a particular product, invited to his house, then killed with a hammer, and then packaged in a sack and carefully concealed.

The cat in the sack :)

Comment: can you provide an evidence that there at least exist hypothesis that this was Harms' intentional pun?

Comment: Harms knew about this man, definitely.

Comment: looks like this version is true. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87

Comment: While this may be an interesting insight, I don't see how it answers the OP's original question.

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! Although your post contains useful information, it does not answer the question. Please edit your post so that it corresponds to the question. Irrelevant answers will be removed. If you wish to add something to another answer, you could invest some time in our site first and earn privileges [to leave comments](http://russian.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) or [to edit answers of other people](http://russian.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit).